# failed with error 10068: “invalid operator: $oid” mongdb & Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, mongodb

im using rails 4.1.1 and mongodb for my web app . and im integrating facebook login but im having an error in saving or in loggin on the user. here's the error

```
Moped::Errors::QueryFailure - The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
  @length=93
  @request_id=2
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="projectsad_development.usersfbs"
  @skip=0
  @limit=0
  @selector={"_id"=>{"$oid"=>BSON::ObjectId('53c467994d696c0bf6000000')}}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 10068: "invalid operator: $oid"
```

ok heres the falling code

```
 <% if current_user %>
      Welcome <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>!
      <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, id: "sign_out" %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %>
  <% end %>
```

heres where i put the current_user def

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= Usersfb.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

Comment: You need to show the failing code and not just the error. But it looks like you are trying to query `{ '_id' => { '$oid' => BSON::ObjectId } }}` when you only need `{ '_id' => BSON::ObjectId }`. $oid is just a serialization convention to represent the type of the data is an ObjectId.

Comment: @NeilLunn i have edited it so can you help me about it... im new at mongodb with rails

Comment: The problem would appear to be in the value that `user_id` is holding in the session. You probably need to look at what you are storing there and how you are storing it.

Comment: im storing data from facebook.

Comment: Any progress on this. I have having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to comment this line from the cookies_serializer.rb helped:

```
        Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json
```

More on this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2949#issuecomment-49261044